# Django shell command to change a value in json data

Tags: python, django

I am a django newbie and i was playing around in django's manage.py shell. Here is something i am trying in the shell:

```
>>> data
[{'primary_program': False, 'id': 3684}, {'primary_program': True, 'id': 3685}]
>>> data[0]
{'primary_program': False, 'id': 3684}
>>> data[1]
{'primary_program': True, 'id': 3685}
>>> data[0].values()
[False, 3684]
>>> data[1].values()
[True, 3685]
>>>
```

How should i give a command here to update the value of `primary_program` in `data[1]` to **False** and keep the rest of the json the same?

EDIT:

This is how i am getting my data. I have a rest framework api and i am using a serializer to read data.

```
>>> from acadprog.models import *
>>> from acadprog.serializers import *
>>> from django.http import Http404
>>> from rest_framework import status
>>> from rest_framework.views import APIView
>>> from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
>>> from rest_framework.response import Response
>>> qs = Student_academic_program.objects.filter(student=2773951)
>>> qs.values()
[{'academic_program_id': 595, 'academic_program_gpa': None, 'student_id': 2773951, 'credits_completed': 28, 'primary_program': False, u'id': 3684}, {'academic_program_id': 596, 'academic_program_gpa': None, 'student_id': 2773951, 'credits_completed': 26, 'primary_program': True, u'id': 3685}]
>>> len(qs.values())
2
>>> data = qs.values('id','primary_program')
>>> data
[{'primary_program': False, 'id': 3684}, {'primary_program': True, 'id': 3685}]
>>> data
[{'primary_program': False, 'id': 3684}, {'primary_program': True, 'id': 3685}]
>>> data[1]['primary_program'] = False
>>> data
[{'primary_program': False, 'id': 3684}, {'primary_program': True, 'id': 3685}]
>>> data['primary_program'][1] = False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/abhishek/projects/texascompletes/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 108, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError
TypeError
>>> data[1]['primary_program'] = False
>>> data
[{'primary_program': False, 'id': 3684}, {'primary_program': True, 'id': 3685}]
```

Comment: That isn't JSON, it's a Python dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `data[1]` is just a dictionary, set the value by key:

```
>>> data = [{'primary_program': False, 'id': 3684}, {'primary_program': True, 'id': 3685}]
>>> data[1]['primary_program'] = False
>>> data
[{'primary_program': False, 'id': 3684}, {'primary_program': False, 'id': 3685}]
```

UPD:

The thing you are getting in the `data` is a queryset. If you need an updated list of dictionaries, cast queryset to `list` before:

```
>>> data = list(qs.values('id','primary_program'))
>>> data[1]['primary_program'] = False
```

If you want to update the value in the database:

```
>>> qs = Student_academic_program.objects.filter(student=2773951)
>>> data = qs[1]
>>> data.primary_program = False
>>> data.save()
```

Also, if you want to set `primary_program` to `False` for all of the student's programs, you can use [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) for bulk update:

```
>>> Student_academic_program.objects.filter(student=2773951).update(primary_program=False)
```

Comment: @crozzfire what do you mean it is not working? Any errors? Where is `data` coming from?

Comment: it didnt throw me any errors...the data is coming from a serializer of a rest framework.. I ll update the question with what i am getting

Comment: i updated the question on how i am getting that data

Comment: @crozzfire gotcha. ok, thanks, what are you going to do with the modified `data`? Do you need to update the `primary_program` value in the database?

Comment: yeah. i have a put() function to update so i ll give a serializer.save() if the data changed in my api_view

Comment: @crozzfire ok, thanks for proving the additional info.I've updated the question, hope any of the notes help.

Comment: the last command you mentioned is returning a value 2 instead of the values

Comment: @crozzfire yeah, but it updates the data in the database, sets `primary_program` to `False` for all of academic programs of the student `2773951`.

Comment: hi. can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592188/django-api-calculate-count-of-responses