# Django api calculate count of responses

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do a survey application in django. My model is as follows:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):    
    resptype = models.ForeignKey(Response)
    ques = models.ForeignKey(Question)    
    response = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
```

Here i am using **rest framework** to send data to my front end. Right now i have my `api` defined as follows:

```
class mymodelList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        surveydata = mymodel.objects.all()
        serialized_surveydata = mymodelSerializer(surveydata, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_surveydata.data)
```

In my app, I have a standard set of 16 questions with multiple choice responses and the choice is saved in the response column in the model.

Now what I am trying to achieve is to calculate the count of responses for each question . ie. For question 1, what is the count that a person responded with 1 or 2 or etc.

Also i would like to know how to send the calculated counts through another json field from the rest framework because I don't have any model defined separately for this data.

EDIT:

This command did the trick for my query but i still not able to figure out how to send it to the front end as a serialized object.

```
x = mymodel.objects.values('ques','response').order_by().annotate(number_of_responses=Count('response'))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a great structure for your model, it would probably be easier to create separate Question and Choice classes. [The Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) actually uses this type of application as an example... take a look at that for some guidance

Answer (score 0):

Check @detail_route or @list_route from [viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) depending on if you want to show this info per question o for all questions at once.

This will allow you to define a custom endpoint to request the information you are asking for. To do so, you may also need to define a custom [serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers) to pass extra data or a [filter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering) if you want to filter by question, user, etc.